# How to work with objects in an array in another document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to display the title object from the array in the document App.js.
Everything works when I use an array without any objects :

(before)
App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import TodoList from './Todo/TodoList'


function App(props) {

const mass = [
    "text1",
    "text2",
    "text3"
]


    return (
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <TodoList name={mass}> </TodoList>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

[image]

But when I add couple objects to array, there is an error (Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {completed, title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.)

(after)
App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import TodoList from './Todo/TodoList'


function App(props) {

const mass = [
    {completed: false, title: "text1"},
    {completed: false, title: "text2"},
    {completed: false, title: "text3"}
]


    return (
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <TodoList name={mass}> </TodoList>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

TodoList.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import TodoItem from './TodoItem'


const styles = {
    ul: {
        color: 'red',
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
    }
}


export default function TodoList(props) {

    return (
        <ul style={
            styles.ul
        }>
            <TodoItem name2={props.name}/> 
        </ul>
    )
}
```

TodoItem.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import App from '../App'


const styles = {
    btn: {
        background: 'none',
        marginLeft: '30px',
    },

    divv: {
        listStyleType: 'none',
        margin:'10px',
        marginLeft: '10px',
        border:'1px solid #ccc',
        padding:'5px',
        width: '250px'
    }

}

const TodoItem = (props) => {


    return (
        <div> 
        {
            props.name2.map((comp, momp) => 
            {
                return (
                    <div style={styles.divv}>
                    <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" /> {momp +1} Test {comp} <button style={styles.btn}>&times;</button>
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    )
            }
                )
            }
            </div>
        )
}

export default TodoItem
```

So in the TodoItem doc I want to work with object named 'title' from array, but not with an array as the whole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `comp.title` instead of `comp` in your TodoItem.js file

when you use array with string items in map function you will see only string (items of array)
but when you use object in your array in map function you will see objects as item